# Unmarshal YAML into unknown struct

Tags: go, yaml

Sorry for the confusing title, I'm having trouble wording this question. So lets say I have a YAML config file like this

```
animals:
  -
    type: whale
    options:
      color: blue
      name: Mr. Whale
    features:
       -
         type: musician
         options:
           instruments:
             - Guitar
             - Violin
```

Very contrived example, but it's directly analogous to what I'm really working with.

So now I have some structs to marshal this config into

```
type Config struct {
  AnimalConfigs []*AnimalConfig `yaml:"animals"`
}

type AnimalConfig struct{
  Type string
  Options map[string]string // ????
  Features []*FeatureConfig
}

type FeatureConfig struct{
  Type string
  Options ????
}
```

So the problem here is that the animal types (whale, etc..), and features (musician, etc...) are not determined ahead of time, they can be added on as separate modules and can each have their own configurations. So say someone is using this library and wants to add their own animal. I do not know what this animal is, what it's options will be, and what it's features will be. I also don't know the structure of the feature's. All I know is that it will have a `type` property, and an `options` property. I would like the developer to be able to add custom animals and features, and my library can just do something like `YourAnimal.Create(yourConfig)`.

I'm using the go-yaml library. As you can see in the AnimalConfig struct, my initial idea was to have the `options` and `features` just be `map[string]string`, and then let the custom module unmarshal that string into their own struct, but that wouldn't work for example with the `musician` feature because `instruments` is a list, not a string. Thanks!

Comment: definetelly your FeatureConfig.Options tend to be ```map[string][]string```. What is the trouble using such a type here?

Answer (score 3):

I think in general what you are asking is how to unmarshal YAML when you don't know the structure which will be produced, yes? If so, what I've done is use [ghodss/yaml](https://github.com/ghodss/yaml) to convert YAML to JSON, then use the standard `encoding/json` to unmarshal. This gets you a `struct` with everything in the YAML doc, but you have to "type switch" your way through it, and key names, of course, may not be known a prioir.

Here's an example: https://play.golang.org/p/8mcuot-lw0y

Comment: Just for an additional info in that type switch you will need to convert the embedded obj or array to the correct to parse the interface to the new type.

if it is an array then you do someStruct["animals"].([][interface{})

If it is an embedded object then you do someStruct["animals"].([][interface{})["options"].(map[string]interface{})["color"]

Answer (score -1):

You could make your config of type `map[string]interface{}` and let the developer using your library decode `interface{}` into required struct.
Example: https://play.golang.org/p/RVqKP09KR8